# How to create ALB that can handle traffic on 2 ports

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want my HTTP traffic on port 3701 and my WS (websocket) traffic on 3702. For a moment I thought that using 2 target groups was the answer, but there doesn't seem to be a way to differentiate between WS and HTTPS traffic using an ALB.

So perhaps using a NLB (network lb) will allow me to differentiate between the two? How can I have one load balancer forward traffic to 2 different ports?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add listeners to the ALB

1 listener for 3701
1 listener for 3702

update the ALB action for each Listener to point to the the correct Target Group